# Issue importing Python packages in Alexa-hosted skill

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying out a basic Alexa skill using Python. Chose Alexa-hosted for the lambda and coded the intent etc. I've added pandas as a dependency in requirements.txt but the runtime is unable to pull it and I get the following error:

> 2024-02-28T19:50:16.310+05:30
> [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas'
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> Copy
> [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pandas' Traceback (most recent call last):

I've checked multiple replies on SO and have also looked at AWS docs. In fact, AWS has the following: https://developer.amazon.com/it-IT/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/alexa-hosted-skills-create.html#dependencies
which basically says add it to requirements.txt. But I can't seem to get it to work. Any help appreciated. Thanks!!